# Why does it seem possible from Physics to say something about orientability locally?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, orientation, quantum-field-theory

In Quantum Field Theory, if I understand correctly, Physicists showed that certain process are not symmetric under time reversal. This should be a local thing, mathematically, and would show that spacetime must be time-orientable (otherwise there is a loop after which a particle should be time-reversed). I think something similar can be said about space-orientability (maybe the CPT-Theorem shows that it's equivalent?).

Sorry about the very non-rigorous question.

Comment: Keep in mind that QFT deals only with small scale processes (how small is debatable but much smaller than the universe). And what we can observe experimentally is only a small part of the space-time. The bottom line is, no.

Comment: It doesn't follow that spacetime is time-orientable. I believe the correct conclusion is that spacetime has a total orientation. It need not be separately space- and time-orientable. The argument is due to Geroch and Horowitz, and can be found in the paper *Global Structure of Spacetimes*.

Comment: @Tyrone : Thank you, this article is giving me the answer to almost all of my questions (except, yet, the existence of Cauchy surfaces)! Your answer is correct, under the additional assumption that particles don't change into antiparticles along closed curves, which is where the global nature comes in mathematically. I'll accept your comment as an answer, if you post it.